# python binning frequency values iteratively

Tags: python, increment, binning

I am just starting with python. I have produced a list of ten random numbers from 1 to 100 and entered them into a list. Now I want to bin their frequencies in a second list also with ten elements each constituting one bin with bin width ten. I initialized the second list, all positions to 0. Then I wanted to simply increment the frequency bins by subtracting 1 from the random values in the first list and divide by ten, making the resulting integers correspond to indices from 0 to 9. This worked fine in C but I am not getting it in python (I realize there are more pythonic ways to doing this). I tried a few things but to no avail. Any quick fixes? here is the code:

```
A = [] #list of random sample expositions
i = 1
while i <= 10: # inner loop to generate random sampling experiment
    x = random.randrange (0, 100, 1)
    A.append (x)
    i += 1
Freq = [0] * 10
for x in A:
    += Freq [(int ((x-1)/10))]
```

Comment: well, what do you think this line `+= Freq [(int ((x-1)/10))]` should do? It's not even correct syntax. Probably you mean `Freq[(int((x-1)/10))] += 1`? Also check floor division `x//10`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the solution. As i said, I am new to python, in C the original syntax was ok.

Comment: I was pretty sure you know the right syntax, given that you have it also here `i += 1`. It's another matter why not use for loop in this case

Comment: Thanks also to Woodford for correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't valid Python:

```
+= Freq [(int ((x-1)/10))]
```

You probably want something closer to this:

```
Freq [(int ((x-1)/10))] += 1
```

Regarding the "pythonicness" of your solution, you could go with something like:

```py
import random

# identify "magic numbers/constants"
N = 10

# use a more appropriate random function with a list comprehension
A = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(N)]

Freq = [0] * N
for x in A:
    # the // operator produces an integer result
    Freq[(x-1)//N] += 1
```

Depending on how you plan to use `Freq` you might consider `collection.Counter` instead:

```
from collections import Counter
Freq = Counter((x-1)//N for x in A)
```